# Defective hard disk: Software evidence of last functional activity?

Tags: windows-10, bios, post, hard-drive-failure

I am calling for Stack's arcanes to know whether it is possible to provide software-based evidence of a Windows 10 laptop's last operational activity before the hard drive went nuts.

The scenario is this: I sold my (used, perfectly functional) laptop to a customer and suspect the carrier not to have handled the package appropriately, resulting in a damaged hard drive. Now I would like to provide my customer evidence of this, hopefully in the form of a proof that the laptop was functional before being sent over (i.e. the last day I used before posting it).

I know there is a command prompt instruction to display the date of system installation, but this solution relies on being able to boot on the hard drive. Is there a similar solution that does not rely on booting on the hard drive? Is there an alternative way of doing what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance,

N.